# How to create .so shared libraries with undefined references - gcc

Tags: gcc, openssl

I have inherited a Makefile which builds a `.so` file.  It is linking with `-lcrypto` from OpenSSL on Ubuntu with gcc 4.7.4.  Critically, it is NOT linking with `-lssl` nor `-ldl`, and when I run `nm -g thelib.so`, it only has the ~15 symbols from openssl crypto. However, they are all `U` (undefined).

I'm refactoring the Makefile on another Ubuntu machine. When I link with `-lcrypto`, it fails due to undefined symbols needed from `dl`.  When I add linking to `-ldl`, those errors go away and linking succeeds. However, my `.so` file is 1.5 MB bigger than the original, and there are at least a hundred symbols related to SSL, which are all `T` (defined), which seem to indicate that `-lssl` is happening implicitly somehow.

While it would seem prudent and good that they are all defined in my case, I need to figure out how to produce the same result just as it is.

So, my question is, how does one get GCC to allow the linking of a `.so` file and accept undefined references?  I've compared our commands, and there are little differences which I've tried to eliminate, but nothing seems to work. I read that it might be related to `-Wl,--no-as-needed`, but i'm using that.  Here's my linker flags.

`g++ -shared -o mylib.so myobjs.o -fPIC -lstdc++ -lm -z defs -Wl,-soname,mylib -Wl,--no-as-needed -lpthread -lcrypto -lz`

Comment: Do you know which exact `-lcrypto` library this `g++` linker step ends up using? For your purpose, it should be a dynamic library, not its static version.

Comment: @ReinierTorenbeek thank you, that was apparently the answer, I installed openssl-devel from Ubuntu, linked with that, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

On the other system (the one with the larger result), OpenSSL has apparently not been built as a shared object, only as a static library (but maybe as PIC, so that you can link the result into a shared object).  You will have to install the packages that provide the shared object and the corresponding `.so` symbolic link.